# Require object is missing when using form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form to send form data like this:

```
= form_tag(admin_pturnovers_path(Pturnover.new), method: :post) do
  = hidden_field_tag :project_id, projectuser.project_id
  = hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id
  = submit_tag :submit, value: "Save"
```

In the controller I check the params:

```
params.require(:pturnover).permit(:project_id, :user_id)
```

When I use the form, I get this error:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing - param is missing or the value is empty: pturnover
```

And indeed it is missing from the `POST` parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "project_id"=>"1076", "user_id"=>"1", "commit"=>"Save"}
```

I would expect this:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "pturnover"=>{"project_id"=>"1076", "user_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

What is wrong here? By using `Pturnover.new` in the `form_tag` I would expect that a proper require parameter would be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By using `Pturnover.new` in the `form_tag`

You are not using `Pturnover.new` in the `form_tag`, only in the `_path` helper `admin_pturnovers_path`.

Try this:

```
= form_tag(admin_pturnovers_path, method: :post) do
 = hidden_field_tag 'pturnover[project_id]', projectuser.project_id
 = hidden_field_tag 'pturnover[user_id]', current_user.id
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`

Just like below

```
= form_for(Pturnover.new, url: admin_pturnovers_path, method: :post) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :project_id, value: projectuser.project_id
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = f.submit "Save"
```

Try above and it will give you the request parameters as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `simple_form_for` instead of `form_for` or `form_tag`.

Since your form is such a quick form, `simple_form` might be a way to go. Such that it becomes:

```
= simple_form_for(Pturnover.new, url: admin_pturnovers_path, method: :post) do |f|
  = f.hidden_field :project_id, value: projectuser.project_id
  = f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id
  = f.submit "Save"
```

**Note:** `simple_form` guesses if you want a `text_field` or `text_area` and adds the label. Definitely, since its `hidden_field`, I believe the form will be hidden, but in a case where you are using `input` in your form and you don't want a label to show, just throw in `label: false` such that you"ll have:

```
f.hidden_field :project_id, label: false, value: projectuser.project_id
```